# form_state->setRedirect(to_a_new_node_page) from the submitForm function, route "does not exist" issue

Tags: 8, redirection, forms

I created a custom module, It generate a custom Form in a page.
When I submit my form, I create a new node.
So, I am redirect to the form page but I would like be redirect to the new node page.

I add this line at the end of my submitForm function :

```
$form_state->setRedirect('node/'.$mynewnode->id());
```

But when I submit my form from the website, I get the empty-white-screen-of-the-death. My apache log :

```
...
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "node/153" does not exist.
...
```

And then, when I go manually to the node/153 page, there isn't any problem. The page work well.

My question : where is my mistake ? How can I set the redirection after create the new node ? Is it possible from the submitForm function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think if you want to use the setRedirect function then you might want to look at its documentation found https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8

You can then base the ff. code from [FormSubmitter::redirectForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormSubmitter.php/function/FormSubmitter%3A%3AredirectForm/8) or [FormSubmitterInterface::redirectForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormSubmitterInterface.php/function/FormSubmitterInterface%3A%3AredirectForm/8). So your code might look something like:

```
$form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical',
  array('node' => $mynewnode->id()),
));
```

You can also find out where is "entity.node.canonical" from by searching in core/modules/node and where it is declared and what it's about.

Hope everything's going great!

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome! :)

Comment: How to setup $form_state->setRedirect() to a path alias instead of using nid?

Comment: @ARUN use Url::fromUserInput.  See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/248601/34673