# Get Route Name from Path

Tags: 8, redirection

I am building a module on drupal 8 to make a redirection after a form is submitted

```
function form_redirect_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'ptt_contact_form_blocks_submit';
}


function ptt_contact_form_blocks_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setRedirect($route_name);
}
```

but for the setRedirect, it needs to have the route name. Like if i want to redirect to node/24, then how can i find the route name of the node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check this one

```
function ptt_contact_form_blocks_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setRedirect('node/24'); // node/$node->nid
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried and seems it does not work... After searching I finally found the approach. 
 https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183081/form-state-setredirectto-a-new-node-page-from-the-submitform-function-route/183088